# in pure MVP, who handles navigation?

Tags: java, mvp

If you want to implement an MVP app without any framework, who would deal with navigation between views?

Right now, I have this navigator interface/class and the presenter has a reference to its implementation. To navigate from login to home, I have the LoginNavigator with a method navigate().

This method is called in one of the presenter methods. However, the next view, the home view, needs data to be displayed and the data is passed to the view in a service class.

So: navigation = presenter, data passing = from service class

The reason I have a separate navigator thing going on is because I didnt want to put Swing-specific code (the switching of panels) into the presenter.

Any recommendations on how to implement this nicely when not using some framework?

Comment: @Oussama the question is about Model-View Presenter

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel yep, it's a bout model-view-presenter... model and view unaware of each other

Answer (score 1):

the best idea is View should have responsibility for navigation action and the presenter would trigger that. but you can even do the action and trigger both in view which is not so clean.

the navigation interface is a great idea because in mvp, the concept says the more the view is silly the better MVP implementation would be.

the navigation mathods is better to be in every view contract separately. for example if you have a register page just a method called `gotToVerifyView()` is enough to handle the navigation. for every view you should have some methods like this to get the handle of navigation to the presenter. this way the presenter is specifying the road map some how.

I dont know whats really wrong with your case of receiving data from a service. explain more so i can edit my answer for better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will post some code in the next days!

Comment: @user3813234 where is the code ;) I have a similar problem here, coming from Java/C# world to javascript (reactjs at the moment), and I would like to have a framework-independent app logic, if you still have question we can exchange ideas